# How to localize aps.net core child class using data annotation localization?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, asp.net-identity, globalization

I am trying to localize my identity model classes with no luck.
E.g. I have `User` class that inherits `IdentityUser` class

```
    public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        // other fieds.....
    }
```

I know that `IdentityUser` class has `Email` property, which I want to localize using data annotation localization followed by [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

I followed the naming conventions for resource files, my data annotation localization doesn't work for inherited properties only.

Is there some naming convention for inherited properties that I am missing here?

I even tried creating custom classes for testing inheritance localization because I thought maybe `IdentityUser` class is a problem because of namespace.
E.G.

```
namespace MyProj.ViewModels
{
    // Used for sending data to User controller.
    public class UserInputModel : UserInputModelParrent
    {
       // Other properties...

    }

    public class UserInputModelParrent
    {
       public string Email { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Notice that the namespace is the same and still kocalization for `Email` property specified in **UserInputModel.mylanguage.resx** doesn't work.
I even tried creating separate file for parrent class, in this case **UserInputModelParrent.mylanguage.resx** , but still no luck.
I even tried using shared resources, but no luck also.

Now, if I add a `[Display(Name= "Email")]` data annotation in parent class, it all works fine, but of course i can't do that for my `IdentityUser` class without overriding property, which I don't want to do.

I've tried google, but no luck for this topic.

Is there a simple resource file naming convention solution, that I am missing here?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: the example is using dependency injection which is built in. Also, it' susing `IStringLocalizer`. Have you tried any of those?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Can u clarify what do you mean by using that approach? As I  understood by this example, `IStringLocalizer` is used for controller localization approach, and dependency injection is used in configuration, if you ask me that, I have used it and it works, but I would need localization using data annotations, because that would be the fastest approach for my project.

Comment: I don't have a specific approach here, but what I meant is what happens if you use DI where you need it. Surely, you don't need to override anything if you get the dependencies that way?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Sorry, I know only the basics of dependency injection, and I can't understand how would I use it for this problem. Can u give some example?

Comment: No worries man, but the tutorial you provided is an example of DI being used to do what (I think) you want to do.